# Is there a way to tile only a part of a texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

So for example, I have this eye texture, and I would want to tile only the area marked with red, so that I would't have to have a high res texture wasting my limited hard drive capasity, which has only a small eye in the middle?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible the way you describe it. What you would usually do is either one of:

1. If the rest of the eye is only a single color, you can rescale the UVs for these parts and even overlap them. (In this example you could also cut off most of the white in the texture)
   [image: eye]
2. If the rest still needs more than a single color, but less details, and you want to use tiling, then you should use two different textures.